# Camel: read and write from same queue with no direct routing

Tags: java, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I am trying to use Camel in two ways in the same application:

1. as background worker thread for processing some slow commands.
2. to queue those command using a synchronous producer.

In the middle Amazon SQS should handle transactionality, retries, distribution, etc of the commands.

However when I add these two routes together:

```
String sqsUri = "aws-sqs://myqueue";
from("direct:cmdQueue").marshal(json).log("Enqueued command").to(sqsUri);
from(sqsUri).unmarshal(json).log("Dequeued command").beanRef("cmdExecutor");
```

Camel shortcircuits the SQS queueing completely and the message is processed synchronously until the end and never sent to SQS.

I tried using multiple CamelContexts and RouteBuilders, but I still get this behaviour.

Is there a way to force the delivery to SQS?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sending the message to a local queue (e.g. vm) and picking it from there and sending to SQS would do the trick. When sending to VM, be sure to set the flag waitForTaskToComplete to false.

Comment: Not a viable solution: sending must guarantee delivery to SQS, otherwise there is risk of message loss.

Comment: What about sending to vm and setting waitForTaskToComplete  to true?